# How to assign dynamically names to a collection of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, dynamic, jbutton

I have to create a collection of JButtons depending of a size of a certain collection. How to create the List of JButtons :button1, button2, button3...dynamically to have something like

```
for (int i=0;i<collection.size();i++){
   JButton button+i = new Button();
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list of buttons (or even an array of buttons) :

```
List<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>(collection.size());
for (int i=0; i < collection.size(); i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    listOfButtons.add(button);
}
```

Comment: As an addition, if you need to be able to tell the buttons apart when they are clicked on, you can use the setActionCommand(String) method inherited from AbstractButton to give each button a distinct string that can be referenced later.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `List<JButton>` and each time through your loop [`add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) the new `JButton` to it.